# Tomcat not reflecting changes after war replacement

Tags: tomcat

I recently replaced a war file from webapps directory. Unfortunately I forgot to shut it down. After realizing the blunder, I shut it down and restarted again but Tomcat is now not reflecting my changes. I have tried replacing the original war but even that is not reflecting. The service is not running at all on Tomcat. However,Apache Tomcat is running as I have checked from services.msc

Is there any other file that needs to be changed. I tried a lot googling out but nothing substantial showed up. At places, I found that previous war has been exploded and needs to be removed but nothing did I get on how to remove those and fix this issue.

Now this is an important service and I am stuck in middle of this mesh. Can anyone direct somewhere.

Edit : I tried to run the wsdl of the service on the server. To my surprise its working fine, the whole wsdl is generated.

Comment: I guess not , only you have put the war in webapps, it will be deployed automatically. You need to provide some logs.

Comment: @Satya, as I found over net, the old war gets exploded and needs to be removed. But I don't know how. Any guesses here??

Comment: Once you have deployed the war file, it will automatically get exploded and remove the old war.

Comment: But its not the case with me...after I replaced the war once everything stopped all of a sudden and I can't get it back to anywhere.